# Rails refresh 'show' partial when :update action executes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have OrdersController `show` action (with `order_info` partial), which displays current status of the order ("paid", "canceled", etc.).

meanwhile, I have callback action `order_callback`, which executes `update` action and changes status of the order in the database when it receives the callback from a payment processor.

What I want to achieve is to update `show` action in real-time to capture changes in order status (e.g. **order paid successfully**).

I tried to use unobtrusive javascript, but did not succeed.

**update.js.erb**

```
$("#order").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'order_info') %>")
```

**show.html.erb**

```
<div id="order">
  <%= render 'order_info' %>
</div>
```

**orders_controller.rb**

```
  def update
    if @order.update_attributes(order_params)
      flash[:success] = "Order updated."
      redirect_to @order
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

**api/orders_controller.rb**

```
def order_callback
  signature = request.headers['X-Signature']
  request_uri = URI(env['REQUEST_URI']).request_uri rescue env['REQUEST_URI']
  if $processor.callback_valid?(signature, request_uri)
    @order = Order.find(params["id"])

    @order.update_attributes(status: params["status"])

    render  status: :ok,
    json: { success: true,
            info: "Successfully updated order." }
  else
    render  status: :unprocessable_entity,
            json: { success: false }
  end 
end
```

I am using rails 4.2.2 with turbolinks enabled.

Comment: If your call to the `update` action was not in JS, your server will not respond in JS, therefore it will not use your `update.js.erb` view. Are you sure you are calling update as an XHR request?

Comment: You are right. And I realized, I don't actually touch update action, just doing update_attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve it with javascript polling. The critical line was to explicitly say which .js partial to render in `respond_to` block

**show.js.erb**

```
$("#order").html("<%= j render 'orders/order_info', locals: {order: @order} %>");
OrderPoller.poll();
```

**orders_controller.rb**

```
def show
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render "orders/show.js.erb" }
      format.html
    end

end
```

**orders.coffee**

```
@OrderPoller =
  poll: ->
    setInterval @request, 5000
  request: ->
    $.get($('#order').data('url'))

jQuery ->
  if $('#order').length > 0
    OrderPoller.poll()
```

**show.html.erb**

```
<%= content_tag :div, id: "order", data: { url: order_path(@order) } do %>
  <%= render 'order_info' %>
<% end %>
```